# Screensaver for Local Screen when using Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, screensaver

I have a server that is always on. It is almost never accessed directly but always via RDP (Remote Desktop). When I do need to access it if the monitor is turned off I often end up having to restart for it to work. As of now I have the screen set to a low brightness, but I would much rather have it show a clock without a static picture or a webpage that I could set (Posterr for example)

It seems that when in Remote Desktop the Lockscreen settings don't work. I have it set to rotate images, but it doesn't rotate while Remote Desktop is active. The screen also doesn't go to sleep while Remote Desktop is active.

### Does anyone know of a way to get the screen to show a screensaver while Remote Desktop is active?